# why several Draw event logs when there is actually one?

Tags: solidity, events, makerdao

I'm looking into the event logs of makerdao's CDP operation, and I'm confused why there are several event logs for 1 cdp operation, like this tx: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x0fb6a8d8f10410c544b27b848319e67a422be883e4252fea639c89a444209685#eventlog, it contains 1 cdp operation: draw dai.

there is only 1 Draw event of 95 Dai:
[image: transfer 95 dai]

while in event logs, there are several event logs(totally 6) with the Topic0 (`0x440f19ba00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`):

[image: event logs]

why is this?

Note: signature of draw event is:

```
  function draw(bytes32 cup, uint wad) public note {
```

here the log is made by the modifier `note`, which is:

```
event LogNote(
    bytes4   indexed  sig,
    address  indexed  guy,
    bytes32  indexed  foo,
    bytes32  indexed  bar,
    uint              wad,
    bytes             fax
) anonymous;

modifier note {
    bytes32 foo;
    bytes32 bar;

    assembly {
        foo := calldataload(4)
        bar := calldataload(36)
    }

    LogNote(msg.sig, msg.sender, foo, bar, msg.value, msg.data);

    _;
}
```

event `LogNote` is `anonymous`, so topic0 is msg.sig instead of the signature of the event. and msg.sig for func dai is: `draw(bytes32,uint256)`, the keccak is: `0x440f19ba0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @dc and @equivrel from makerdao's chat channel [link1](https://chat.makerdao.com/channel/dev?msg=4tGGBkczPnojct67r) [link2](https://chat.makerdao.com/channel/dev?msg=hELu9Ba5L6meESqLG)

> There are a quite a number of sai functions that produce multiple log entries - it's due to the use of DSNote which produces a log events each time an internal note function is called
>
> @dc

So the 6 event logs comes from:

- 3 direct calls of `chi()`
- 1 direct call of `rhi()`
- 1 un-direct call of `chi()` (safe() -> tab() -> chi())
- 1 call of `draw()`